# C# - Automapper :: convertir objeto a un objeto complejo

Tags: c#, automapper

Tengo la siguiente estructura de Request y Response:

```
public class Action
{
    public class Create
    {
        public class Request
        {
            public string operationdate { get; set; }
            public string action { get; set; }
            public string identificationaccount { get; set; }
            public string observation { get; set; }
            private ErrorModel.Error errorrow = new ErrorModel.Error();
            public ErrorModel.Error ErrorRow { get { return errorrow; } set { errorrow = value; } }
        }
        public class Response : Request
        {
            public Int32 version { get; set; }
            public string groupcode { get; set; }
            public bool active { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

y quiero mapear a la siguiente estructura de DTO:

```
public class GroupDTO
{
    public Int64 idGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
    public string GroupDate { get; set; }
    public string Obs01 { get; set; }
    public string Obs02 { get; set; }
    public string Obs03 { get; set; }
    public string Obs04 { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    private List<ActionModelDTO> _Actions = new List<ActionModelDTO>();
    public List<ActionModelDTO> Actions { get { return _Actions; } set { _Actions = value; } }
}

public class ActionModelDTO
{
    public Int64 idAction { get; set; }
    public string ActionDate { get; set; }
    public Int32 Version { get; set; }
    public Int32 idGroup { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    private ActionDetailModelDTO _ActionDetailModel = new ActionDetailModelDTO();
    public ActionDetailModelDTO ActionDetailModel { get { return _ActionDetailModel; } set { _ActionDetailModel = value; } }
    private ActionUserDetailModelDTO _ActionUserDetailModel = new ActionUserDetailModelDTO();
    public ActionUserDetailModelDTO ActionUserDetailModel { get { return _ActionUserDetailModel; } set { _ActionUserDetailModel = value; } }
}

public class ActionDetailModelDTO
{
    public Int64 idActionDetailModel { get; set; }
    public Int32 idActionType { get; set; }
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
}

public class ActionUserDetailModelDTO
{
    public Int64 idActionUserDetailModel { get; set; }
    public string UserAccount { get; set; }
    public string UserObservation { get; set; }
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

El mapeo sería el siguiente:

1. Action.Create.Request.operationdate => ActionModelDTO.ActionDate
2. Action.Create.Request.action => ActionDetailModelDTO.ActionType
3. Action.Create.Request.identificationaccount =>         ActionUserDetailModelDTO.UserAccount
4. Action.Create.Request.observation => ActionUserDetailModelDTO.UserObservation

El objeto al que se tendría que mapear es GroupDTO... es la primera vez que uso Automapper, y me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

Los campos que no figuran en el mapeo que especifiqué se completan luego que el objeto se persista en DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar lo que necesitas primero debes configurar las clases (y propiedades de darse el caso) de los objetos que deseas convertir, de esta forma:

```
using AutoMapper;

public class TuClase
{
   private MapperConfiguration config;
   private IMapper mapper;

   public Program()
   {
      this.config = new MapperConfiguration(m =>
      {
         m.CreateMap<Action.Create.Request, ActionModelDTO>()
            .ForMember(to => to.ActionDate, from => from.MapFrom(x => x.operationdate));
         });
         this.mapper = config.CreateMapper();
      }
   }
}
```

Te darás cuenta que para que las propiedades de tu objeto **Action.Create.Request** y **ActionModelDTO** tomen el valor correspondiente debes especificar de forma explícita dichos atributos.

Finalmente para pasar de un objeto a otro tienes que realizar el mapeo correspondiente de esta manera

```
public void MiMetodo()
{
   Action.Create.Request item = new Action.Create.Request
   {
      action = "test",
      observation = "mensaje",
      identificationaccount = "otro",
      operationdate = "22-09-2024"
   };

   ActionModelDTO item2 = mapper.Map<ActionModelDTO>(item);
}
```

Cabe mencionar que si quieres realizar tu mapeo al revés sólo debes agregar en la configuración

```
m.CreateMap<ActionModelDTO, Action.Create.Request>()
```

que no es otra cosa, que los objetos al revés ;)

Nos comentas como te va =)